# Combining concatenate and if in Excel formulas

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

How would I add the `IF(ISBLANK` formula to this formula

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT('Unapplied Report'!A5,"0000"),TEXT('Unapplied Report'!C5,"000"),TEXT('Unapplied Report'!D5,"0000"))
```

without getting any errors. I've tried it a couple times and just get formula error messages.

Comment: Are you trying to check the result of the concatenate for blankness, or each of the three sub-elements?

Comment: basically the link pulls cells from 3 columns in sheet 1 into sheet 2( using the concatenate and text formula) however some of those cells in sheet 1 are blank but return "00000000" because of my use of the TEXT formula. So I want it to show a blank instead of the 000000. if that makes any sense

Comment: So, if A5 is not blank, C5 is blank and D5 is not blank, it should concatenate only A5 and D5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for this instead?

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(ISBLANK('Unapplied Report'!A5),"",TEXT('Unapplied Report'!A5,"0000")),
             IF(ISBLANK('Unapplied Report'!C5),"",TEXT('Unapplied Report'!C5,"000")),
             IF(ISBLANK('Unapplied Report'!D5),"",TEXT('Unapplied Report'!D5,"0000")))
```

This will concatenate only those cells that are not blank.

Comment: Can this be extended to work with 15 cells, without making the formula huge?

Comment: @GreyCloud Unfortunately no :( I don't know how to do that. I could chain a formula across many cells to achieve that.

Comment: Expecting Excel to have syntax and functionality like a real programming language?! XD

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
=IF('Unapplied Report'!A5="","",TEXT('Unapplied Report'!A5,"0000"))&IF('Unapplied Report'!C5="","",TEXT('Unapplied Report'!C5,"0000"))&IF('Unapplied Report'!D5="","",TEXT('Unapplied Report'!D5,"0000"))
```

Comment: the `if(A1="", "empty", "not empty")` is pretty simple and takes less typing/space than isBlank. Difference in functionality vs isBlank: **=""** will count Forumula Blanks as blank, where **IsBlank** will not. IsBlank will consider a formula blank as NOT blank. from http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/352850-difference-between-isempty-isblank-%3D.html